# About MongoDB add shard and router server need to restart?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I build a MongoDB sharding environment and want to test the performance of migration data.

1. I insert one billion rows in a collection in Replica Set A.
2. I added another shard setting Replica Set B.
3. MongoDB starts to balance chunks between those shards.

After balancing is finished, I found out I can't look up some data.

Because those data have been moved to Replica Set B, only when I restart all mongo router service am I able to query them.

Is it a normal and inevitable procedure, or is there any way to reload the whole system (through mongo shell command or anything else)?

Thank you !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a command that it seems help to reload the router config

```
db.adminCommand({"flushRouterConfig":1});
```

2017-05-18 After testing, it works!